# What is the cleanest way to get displayed row number in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a set of images displayed in a series of bootstrap rows, each one looking like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">im1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">im2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">im3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">im4</div>
</div>
```

.

When this set of rows is rendered, the number of columns per row will depend on the pixel width of the browser.  Now, suppose that I want to provide row numbers for the user, but I want the row numbers to be associated with the rows the user sees, not the rows designated by class.  What's the cleanest way to obtain and display these row numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the elements and compare their vertical offset or position on the page. In the example below I use the native JavaScript `.offsetTop` property, but there are many ways (both native and using jQuery) to find this information.

#### `Demo`

```js
var count; 
$(window).on('load, resize', function() {
    var offset, oldcount = count; count = 0;
    $('.row [class^="col"]').each(function(){
        if(offset !== this.offsetTop) ++count, offset = this.offsetTop;
    }); 
    if(count !== oldcount) {
        console.log(count);
        // ... do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This is nice.  I didn't know about the offsetTop property, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Tiny Giant's lead using .each, $(window).on('load, resize', ...), and element.offsetTop.  To get a set of row numbers and associate them with the columns, I created an object called "offsets" with row positions as properties.  (Sets still aren't working on all browsers, so I mimicked one with an object.)  Converting the keys of that object to an array gave me a sorted list of unique row offsets.  I could then use .indexOf to convert column offsets to row numbers for each column.

```
var display_rows = function () {
    var s = '.row [class^="col"]'
    ,   offsets = {};
    $(s).each(function(){
        offsets[this.offsetTop] = 1;
    });
    var offset_keys = Object.keys(offsets);
    $(s).each(function(){
        var row = offset_keys.indexOf(card.offsetTop + '') + 1;
        console.log(row);
        // display row number where you want it.  
        // e.g. $(this).find('.coordinate').html(row)
    });
}
$(window).on('load, resize', function() {
    diplay_rows();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    display_rows();
});
```